# Creating a data frame during a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have the following bit of code

```
for category in ['a','b','c','d']:

 'HML_Flag_'+ category = pd.merge(category,HML_base_table,'inner','random')
 'HML_Flag_'+ category = 'HML_Flag_'+ category[['random','HML']]
 'HML_Flag_'+ category = 'HML_Flag_'+ category.groupby('HML').count()
```

The error I am getting is as follows

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

How do I create dataframes and change them for every cycle within the loop?

Comment: You are getting the error because the left side variables are not valid and also you cannot create variables dynamically using strings.

Comment: What would be the best way to write something like this then?

Comment: Could you provide some input data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Note: This method is highly not recommended

```
for category in ['a','b','c','d']:
    exec("%s=%d" % ('HML_Flag_'+ category , 5))
print HML_Flag_a
```

Instead of above code use below,

```
dic={}
for category in ['a','b','c','d']:
    dic['HML_Flag_'+ category]= 5
print dic['HML_Flag_a']
```

Note: As per your code, it reassigns the value in that same variable.